# How to add pagination on user list in Moodle?

Tags: moodle

I have more user in user list it so difficult for find user, so I want to add *pagination* at user list in **Moodle**

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the class `flexible_table` or `table_sql` located in `lib/tablelib.php`. Those, while not necessarily easy to set-up initially, are very useful classes to display a list of items, with pagination, sorting, etc...